# Unable to refresh Materialized view manually in Oracle12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, materialized-views

I created a materialized view as show below:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ORA2ORA_DW.INVOICE_AGG
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH FORCE
ON DEMAND
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE 
AS
SELECT C.CUSTOMERID , C.CUSTOMERNAME,  SUM(I.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY, MAX(I.UNITPRICE) AS UNITPRICE, MIN(I.TAXAMOUNT) AS AMOUNT, 
AVG(I.TAXRATE) AS TAX, VARIANCE(I.LINEPROFIT)AS LINEPROFIT_VAR, STDDEV(I.LINEPROFIT) AS LINEPROFIT_STDEV, COUNT(I.INVOICELINESKEY) AS ROW_COUNT
FROM ORA2ORA_DW.INVOICELINES I, ORA2ORA_DW.CUSTOMERS C
WHERE  I.CUSTOMERSKEY=C.CUSTOMERSKEY
GROUP BY  C.CUSTOMERID , C.CUSTOMERNAME
ORDER BY C.CUSTOMERID;
```

but when I try to refresh it using this command "EXEC DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('INVOICE_AGG');", it gives me this error: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: Try putting the command in an anonymous PL/SQL block (i.e. `BEGIN ... END;`. Also, I would lose the `ORDER BY` clause, as it will add a lot of overhead processing and disk I/O for the refresh. Save ordering for the actual user query, as it may differ from what you put in the MV and you'd only be duplicating the overhead.

Comment: Additionally, you never said which tool you used to run that `exec dbms_mview.refresh` command. Are you sure it supports the `exec` command?

Comment: I am using dbeaver to run this query. Anyways I tried putting the command in PL/SQL block:

`BEGIN
DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('INVOICE_AGG');
END;`

It works perfectly now. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Yes, seconding @pmdba's recommendation to remove the `ORDER BY`. An ORDER BY clause is allowed in the CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW statement. It is used only during the initial creation of the materialized view. It is not used during a full refresh or a fast refresh. [see](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/basicmv.htm#DWHSG8208)